# Scan Dynamo DB with boto3 for array of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, botocore

Need to scan Dynamo DB having records with list of dictionary objects.
Below is my sample data

```
'toAddr': [{'type': 'email', 'address': 'aaa@gmail.com'}, {'type': 'email', 'address': 'bbb@gmail.com'}]}
```

Below lines of code would do the needful for me.

```
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table(table_name)
response = table.scan(FilterExpression="contains (#items, :itemVal)",
                      ExpressionAttributeNames={"#items": "toAddr"},
                      ExpressionAttributeValues={":itemVal":{"address":"aaa@gmail.com",
                                                              type":"email"}})
```

However i would like to build the filter Expression in below format

```
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('toAddr').contains('itemVal'),
                      ExpressionAttributeValues={":itemVal":{"address":"aaa@gmail.com",
                                                    "type":"email"}})
```

But this would result in an error

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions: keys: {:itemVal}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@tommy, Your answer is almost correct except we should not use json.dumps

```
itemVal = {"address": "aaa@gmail.com", "type": "email"}

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('toAddr').contains((itemVal)
)
```

The above one helped to scan results.

Comment: That's odd, I had to use `json.dumps` to make it work when I was testing it for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `contains` function only allows you to search for a string in a string or for a string in a set. You will need to restructure your data, or you will need to filter the results of your scan in your python code.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Comment: My first set of code works my second set using Attr is not working, in first set also I am using contains but in different format

Answer (score 3):

In the second code snippet `'itemVal'` is just a string and it is not matched with `:itemVal` from `ExpressionAttributeValues`. In the format you are proposing you can get rid of `ExpressionAttributeValues` and instead use something like this:

```
itemVal = {"address": "aaa@gmail.com", "type": "email"}

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('toAddr').contains(json.dumps(itemVal))
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not return any scan result it just returns empty list.